# How to calculate the heat transfer rate between cold and hot bodies?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

I am a hobbyist when it comes to physics, This question popped up in my head while cooking and researched the topic but wasn't able to find the correct way to scientifically translate the question (Maybe):-

While cooking I had a dish with cold yogurt which I will add to 2 hot items 1st hot heated bread, 2nd boiled chickpea. Now the question is does it make a difference in terms of heating (temperature) the yogurt to apply both together or separate?

Might seem like a silly question but it's been in my head for some time now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The timing is important here. If everything was done in a very quick sequence, the result would be the same. So we assume that there is a meaningful interval, say, 10 seconds, between adding two hot ingredients to the yogurt.

The second thing we'll assume is that at the start of your experiment, the heating of your bread and boiling of your chickpeas is complete, i.e., they start losing heat.

The main idea we'll use to answer your question is that the rate of cooling (among other things, like thermal resistance) is proportional to the difference between the temperature of a body being cooled and the surrounding air. This, generally, means that, everything else the same, hot bodies are cooled faster than worm bodies.

In your case, we'll assume that the boiled chickpeas are hotter than the heated bread and therefore will be losing heat faster. So, if you wanted to maximize the temperature of the yogurt, you would add chickpeas first.

What also matters here is the amount of ingredients. For instance, if you had just one very hot chickpea and a lot of not so hot bread, you would have to start with bread, because, in ten seconds, it would lose more heat than one chickpea even though its cooling rate is lower. So, we've made another implicit assumption that the amount (using a loose term here) of chickpeas in your recipe is comparable with the amount of bread.

I ask myself a similar question when I add milk to my coffee: should I do it right after the coffee is in the cup or, say, 10 seconds later, when I am ready to drink it. If my objective is to get the hottest possible mix at the time I start drinking, I should add milk right away - to reduce the rate of cooling.